# Flashlight toggle script initiates flash on startup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On startup the flashlight toggle script mode toggles ON/OFF, I'm not sure how to patch this.

I believe it's coming from `IEnumerator Start()` but, I've tried changing the `yield return new WaitForSeconds` to 0 but that didn't change a thing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Vuforia;

public class FlashlightAPI : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Start()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);

        hasTorch = CameraDevice.Instance.SetFlashTorchMode(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.000f);
        CameraDevice.Instance.SetFlashTorchMode(false);
    }

    bool torchState = true, hasTouch = false;
    public bool hasTorch;

    public FlashlightAPI(bool torchState, bool hasTorch)
    {
        this.torchState = torchState;
        this.hasTorch = hasTorch;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);` ment to do? remove these lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Zero is too long

`Wait` makes Unity wait until *the next frame after* the condition has passed. In this case, it waits for the first frame *after at least 0 seconds* have elapsed, meaning that it waits 1 frame.

If you want it to happen instantly, you need to remove the `Wait`s entirely.

```
void Start()
{
    hasTorch = CameraDevice.Instance.SetFlashTorchMode(true);
    CameraDevice.Instance.SetFlashTorchMode(false);
}
```

However as you're fiddling with an external device (the phone's camera), this may still cause the light to flash and you should refer to the documentation to resolve the issue. As `CameraDevice` is not a Unity class I cannot do this for you.